# Aplicar onBackPressed en un fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, onbackpressed

¿Como aplicar `onBackPressed()` en un `fragment`?

No funciona igual que en una actividad, a continuacion explico exactamente mi caso:

Necesito que al estar en mi `fragment` al presionar el boton "atras" que traen todos los android por defecto, este redirija a otro `fragment`

Comment: Tu usas un `FragmentManager`para cambiar de fragmentos?

Answer (score 1):

Si usas un `FragmentManager`, la respuesta es bien simple. Solo agrega `.addToBackStack(tag)` a tu transacción. Ejemplo:

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance(),"main").addToBackStack("main")
            .commit();
```

Comment: modificare el post colocando mi codigo donde salto de un fragment a otro para que me indiques, podrias hacerlo?

Comment: Me pediste de decirte como colgar un cuadro, y te di martillo y clavo. Si quieres que te ayuda ponerlo, tienes que mostrarme tu casa. ;) Si quieres más ayuda vas a tener que compartir el código que has hecho. en el caso de Android significa: La `Activity`, el código donde quieres ejecutar la acción (por ejemplo un `OnClickListener` y en la mayoría de los casos es útil de agregar el layout de las clases que usas.

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro un ejemplo de como lo hacía yo:

Esto va cuando vas a abrir un fragmento:

```
....replace(R.id.container, new ChatView()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Dentro de tu fragmento colocas el método `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

    }
```

Comment: dentro del fragmento no me pertime o reconoce el metodo onBackPressed()

Comment: onBackPressed() es un método de la `Activity` que contiene tus fragmentos. tienes que hacer un @Override alla

Comment: Erny tal como dice Stefan, debes de hacer @Override, así lo tengo arriba si te fijas bien :)

Answer (score 1):

Regularmente quien determina la transacción de Fragmentos es la Activity, la opción más sencilla es llamar el `onBackPressed()` de la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

y en el método `onBackPressed()` de la Activity realizas obtención del Fragment que se agrego al BackStack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  else
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Para que esto funcione, recuerda agregar los fragmentos al BackStack con `addToBackStack()` :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: ok lo intentare, lo que sucede es que ya usaba ese metodo veré como lo implemento, (hola @Elenasys como estas? estabas perdida, entrego esta semana ando de los nervios, tienes tiempo?)

Comment: Que tal Erny  todo bíen, tu proyecto es de la escuela?

Comment: recuerda que te comente que era la tesis (ese minúsculo e insignificante detalle xD)

Comment: ohhhhhh es algo importante en realidad! =) °

Comment: bueno, si tienes tiempo y no te molesto pasa por aqui http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52073/discussion-between-stefan-nolde-and-erny-jose-hidalgo-correa (no te rias de mi aun no se hacer chats xD)

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta, si lo que quieres es que cuando le das para atras vuelva al fragment anterior añade este fragmento de codigo cuando creas el fragment.

```
NombreDeTuFragmentManager.popBackStack();
```