# La pila de fragments no retrocede de uno en uno, se cierran todos los fragments a la vez

Tags: android, android-fragment, onbackpressed

He creado un proyecto de prueba con la plantilla "Navigation Drawer Activity".

Al seleccionar alguna de las opciones que hay por defecto, se abre su respectivo fragment que indica su contenido (home, gallery, slider...)

Lo que trato de hacer es añadir subcategorías a una categoría concreta. Por ejemplo, quisiera añadir subcategorías a Gallery y de esta forma navegar de gallery a gallery2 y de gallery2 a gallery3.

Navegar “hacia adelante” lo hace correctamente, el problema surge al **retroceder**.
Al pulsar el botón de retroceder, en vez de pasar de gallery3 a gallery2 y luego a gallery1, salta directamente a home (ni siquiera a gallery).

Utilizo el código siguiente y he probado con "add" y "replace" en la transacción sin ningún resultado:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment{

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private ImageView boton_cambio;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

        boton_cambio = root.findViewById(R.id.button);
        boton_cambio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment galleryFragment_2 = new GalleryFragment2();
                FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransacion = fragManager.beginTransaction();
                fragTransacion.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, galleryFragment_2);
                fragTransacion.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTransacion.commit();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

Para pasar de Gallery2 a Gallery3, el código es el siguiente:

```
public class GalleryFragment2 extends Fragment{

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private ImageView boton_cambio;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery2, container, false);

        boton_cambio = root.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        boton_cambio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment galleryFragment_3 = new GalleryFragment3();
                FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransacion = fragManager.beginTransaction();
                fragTransacion.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, galleryFragment_3);
                fragTransacion.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTransacion.commit();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

En MainActivity he sobre escrito el método **onBackPressed()** con lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Al código anterior le puse un "Toast" para ver que condición se cumplía y siempre entra en el "if", nunca en el "else"

No acabo de ver si es que me estoy dejando algo o tengo un error de concepto.

El código expuesto lo he realizado después de consultar **stack**, **backstack** tanto en SO en español como en inglés, pero la mayoría de las respuestas tienen 2 o 3 años y no sé si eso puede afectar.

Entre otros he consultado lo siguiente sin éxito:

[FragmentTransaction se lleva contenido del fragment anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53787/fragmenttransaction-se-lleva-contenido-del-fragment-anterior/53827#53827)

[Aplicar onBackPressed en un fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45423/aplicar-onbackpressed-en-un-fragment/45556#45556)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction (obsoleto en API 28)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks (obsoleto en API 28)

Comment: Agrega GalleryFragment2 puede ser que tengas algo definido ahi que este provocando el cierre de todos., saludos

Comment: He abierto un proyecto nuevo y obtengo un resultado distinto. Al retroceder paso del fragment 3 al home más el contenido del propio 3, luego al 2 y luego al home (el 1 lo salta). Voy a ver si organizo un poco lo que tengo en la cabeza y en el escritorio, porque aquí el que falla soy yo, no el código :(  De todas formas pongo el código de GalleryFragment2, por si veis algo que no vea yo, pero creo que son idénticos, salvo las llamadas a sus respectivas clases y layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un fragment hazlo de dicha manera te paso captura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Beras que se te creara tanto el archivo java como el layout, entonces en el mainactivity el primero se carga de esta manera.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, Home.newInstance(), Home.FragmentHome).commit();
```

Esto lo que hace es cargar dicho fragmento pero siempre lo tienes en memoria. La función de NewInstance solamente entra la priemra vez cuando tiene que crear el fragmento no hagas cada vez que haces click cargar el fragmento porque te quedaras sin memoria en el dispositivo.

Para hacer que al tirar atras funcione correctamente lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(final Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()){
        if(frag.getTag() != null) {
            switch (frag.getTag()) {
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Yo lo hago de esta manera cada fragment le pongo un Tag cuando los cargo en el fragmentmanager les digo que tag es cada uno de esta manera al tirar hacia atras cargo Fragmentmanager y con la funcion de getFragments() me dice todos los fragmentos que tengo en memoria si esta el que estoi buscando que me lo cargue de nuevo o que tire hacia atras haciendo " super.onBackPressed(); "

Comment: Voy a probar lo que dices de manera aislada y si me funciona intentaré asimilarlo al DrawerActivity.